# localtime() is showing 0 microseconds since 1970 as one hour

Tags: c, linux, timezone, localtime, timeval

I have a timeval which is 0 seconds and 0 microseconds. I am therefore expecting zero hours:

```
//Create a timeval representing 0 microseconds since 1970 
struct timeval test;
test.tv_sec = 0;
test.tv_usec = 0;

struct tm *nowtm2;
time_t nowtime2;
nowtime2 = test.tv_sec;
nowtm2 = localtime(&nowtime2);

//This should output 0, but is outputting 1
std::cout << "h: " << nowtm2->tm_hour;
```

However, `h` keeps outputting the value 1, which I presume is because `localtime()` is adding an extra hour for daylight savings.

How can I prevent this extra hour being added?

UPDATE

```
std::cout << "d: " << nowtm2->tm_isdst << std::endl;
```

outputs zero

Comment: Have you checked the `tm_isdst` member of the `struct tm`?

Comment: Just did- outputs zero.... :s

Comment: check your environment... most likely, you machine is in the CET time zone; it's definitely not daylight saving since 1.1.1970 00:00 is in winter

Comment: @ammoQ wouldnt that add 3/4 hours, rather than just one?

Comment: No, CET is GMT+1; what's the output of `echo $TZ`?

Comment: @ammoQ I have just checked nowtm2->tm_zone and its "BST" (british summer time) which is obviously 1 away from GMT....

Comment: Jan 1st should not fall into BST... strange... any reason why you don't use `gmtime()`?

Comment: But the machine doing the conversion **now** is set to **BST** now. @ammoQ

Comment: If you don't want local time, don't use `localtime()`; use `gmtime()`!